# Selenium in Python: Selecting an Option

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette

I am having no luck selecting an option from a `<select>` using selenium.  I have referenced https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver

The html code is as follows:

```
<select name="Dropdownlistrequests" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;Dropdownlistrequests\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="Dropdownlistrequests" style="height:51px;width:174px;Z-INDEX: 104; LEFT: 280px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 72px">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Previous Days</option>
    <option value="2">Previous Month</option>
    <option value="3">Last 12 Hours</option>
    <option value="4">Demand Poll</option>
    <option value="6">Custom</option>
</select>
```

I have tried

```
requests = driver.find_element_by_id("Dropdownlistrequests")
requests.click()
for option in requests.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == "Custom":
        option.click()
        break
```

And

```
requests = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("Dropdownlistrequests"))
requests.select_by_value("6")
```

And

```
b.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Dropdownlistrequests']/option[text()='Custom']").click()
```

Instead of selecting the appropriate option the browser does nothing and moves on to the next bit of code.  Could it have something to do the the javascript that is triggered by the onchange?

**To provide some more context**: I am running windows 7 enterprise and using selenium with marionette and Firefox developer edition 49.0a2

**Update:** This only sems to happen when usoing Marionette in python. I tried this same code in Java with and without Marionette and it worked

Comment: can you please try using option.get_attribute("innerText") instead to acquire "Custom"? and can you please introduce a bit "wait" after you click on "request" so that the click will not be too fast to be missed.

Comment: @YuZhang the current loop will reach the `option.click()` statement, if I change the conditional to `if option.get_attribute("innerText") == "Custom":` the `click()` statement is never reached.  Waiting after the click also does nothing.  I'm baffled.

Comment: Try: `requests=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("Dropdownlistrequests"))
requests.select_by_visible_text("Custom")`

Comment: @ishikun I've tried that too with no success

Comment: I'm wondering if it's the Marionette driver. Do you have a requirement to use the FF dev version? You might try the old driver and see if it works. You may have found a bug. Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @JeffC when I started this project FF 47 was not supported by Marionette with python (official instructions recommend FF Dev : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) and  FF 47 was also not supported by the standard selenium web driver (wires I think).  Let me try it without marionette or with an older version.

Comment: @JeffC No luck whenever I'm using Marionette.  See my update above.

Comment: Yeah... that's a bummer. You should enter a bug for this issue if one doesn't exist already.

Comment: @JeffC I submitted on here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If non of the work in your case you should try `.execute_script()` as below :-

```
select = driver.find_element_by_id("Dropdownlistrequests")

driver.execute_script("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }",select, "Custom")
```

**Edited** :- Above code only select the provided option from select box. If you want trigger the `onchange` event as well when option selected, try as below :-

```
select = driver.find_element_by_id("Dropdownlistrequests")

driver.execute_script("showDropdown = function (element) {var event; event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window); element.dispatchEvent(event); }; showDropdown(arguments[0]);",select)
# now you dropdown will be open


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Dropdownlistrequests']/option[text()='Custom']").click()
#this will click the option which text is custom and onchange event will be triggered.
```

Hope it will work for you..:)

Comment: I tired the above code and it changed the value of the `<select>` but did not actually click the option thus not triggering the necessary JavaScript

Comment: You mean you like as simly open selectbox show all options and then click at option..Right??

Comment: Your code just changes the label in the select box.  I just want to click the 6th option I do not need all the options to be shown.

Comment: @pmaurais please try with my updated answer. it will trigger the onchange event...:)